# Регулярное выражение для поиска строки определённой длины в любой строке

Tags: регулярные-выражения, qregexp

Нужно выбрать строку точно из 5 цифр в произвольной строке, например, в этих строках будет выдано 12345

```
12345
12345бла
бла*12345
бла-12345+бла
```

в этих строках подходящей последовательности нет

```
бл0а9876
987654
бла+0987654321-бла
```

У меня есть решение, но я хочу ещё варианты.
Мой вариант **(?:\D|^)(\d{5})(?:\D|$)** и выбрать первую группу.
FLAVOR=ECMAScript, точнее, VBScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте

```
(?:\D|^)(\d{5})(?!\d)
```

**Подробности**

- `(?:\D|^)` - любой символ, кроме цифры (`\D`), или (`|`) начало строки (`^`)
- `(\d{5})` - захватывающая подмаска №1: пять любых цифр из набора символов ASCII
- `(?!\d)` - блок предварительного просмотра вперёд, который требует отсутствия цифры сразу после текущей позиции в строке (т.е. после пяти цифр не должно быть другой цифры).

Вам нужно только значение захватывающей подмаски, т.е. в VBScript нужно получить значение `match.SubMatches(0)`.

Пример кода на VBScript:

```
Dim regEx As Object, Matches As Object, m As Object
Dim str As String

Dim coll As Collection
Set coll = New Collection

str = "12345 12345бла бла*12345 бла-12345+бла |||| бл0а9876 987654 бла+0987654321-бла"

Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
regEx.Pattern = "(?:\D|^)(\d{5})(?!\d)"
regEx.Global = True

Set Matches = regEx.Execute(str)
If Matches.count > 0 Then
 For Each m In Matches
  coll.Add(m.SubMatches(0))
  Wscript.Echo(m.SubMatches(0))
 Next m
Else
  Wscript.Echo("Совпадений не найдено.")
End If

If coll.count > 0 Then Wscript.Echo("Кол-во совпадений: " & coll.count)
```

Результат:

```
12345
12345
12345
12345
Кол-во совпадений: 4
```

Comment: А почему первая группа такая? возможно же сделать так же негативный просмотр назад `(?<!\d)`  и тогда можно избавиться от захвата в группу нужных цифр

Comment: @ipatev_nn Библиотеки регулярных выражений в VBScript / VBA не поддерживают блоки предпросмотра назад.

Comment: Спасибо!
Я пока пытаюсь осознать как оно работает.
Какие могут быть причины использовать тот или иной вариант шаблона, кроме личных предпочтений?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, понял, спасибо за объяснение!

Comment: @0617  Я добавил объяснение шаблона в ответ.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew
Я понял: в случае, если нужно найти не одно, а несколько вхождений, то мой паттерн не работает в ситуации, когда подходящие строки отделяет ровно один символ. Ваш паттерн работает идеально.
+12345+67890+09876+54321+
мой паттерн найдёт 12345 и 09876
ваш выберет все 4 вхождения.